# Turn off iPhone lock on home wifi

Tags: iphone, screen-lock

Is it possible to / is there an app that can turn off your iPhone lock when the device is connected to your home WiFi?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but once you have an iPhone with the fingerprint reader it's no longer a hassle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible if your iPhone is not jailbroken.

If your iPhone is jailbroken, then there are a couple apps that let you disable the passcode on the lock screen when you are connected to your home (or any trusted) WiFi:

- [AutoProtect](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/05/10/autoprotect/)
- [CleverPin](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/04/18/cleverpin-for-the-iphone-is-an-innovative-way-to-balance-ease-of-use-with-passcode-security/)